# Start Tableau on iPad

Tags: ipad, visualization, tableau-api

I have just downloaded Tableau on my iPad.
However it asks me for a server at start.
What should I use?
I know there is a free tableau server. What is it?

After I entered will I be able to open my tableau files designed on my mac?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Tableau Public is the free version of Tableau Server:http://www.tableausoftware.com/tableau-public-ipad
2. No. The Tableau mobile app is essentially a reskinned mobile browser optimised for use with published Tableau workbooks, and thus can only be used in conjunction with Tableau Public, Tableau Online (a SaaS version of Tableau Server) or an on-premise installation of Tableau Server

Comment: so what is the "server" it asks me to enter?

Comment: public.tableausoftware.com is the URL for Tableau Public. 
You also need to have a valid user account, so please register here: https://public.tableausoftware.com/auth/signup